# Programming a hole / empty space in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

i'd like to programm something like a hole in three.js.
it should be like, e.g. a 3x3x3 cube with an 1x1x1 hole in it. is there a possibility, that i first use something like cubegeometry and afterwards another "geometry" that cuts out the stuff that i want to have deleted? an deletion geometry? :D

Thanks :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are looking to "cut" things out in certain shapes, you may be interested in [this post](http://chandler.prallfamily.com/2011/12/constructive-solid-geometry-with-three-js/) on a Constructive Solid Geometry library.  It comes with a wrapper for THREE.js objects.

It lets you do things like this:

```
var cube = new CSG.cube();
var sphere = CSG.sphere({radius: 1.3, stacks: 16});
var geometry = cube.subtract(sphere);
```

=>

[image]

[Here](http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2011/12/10/constructive-solid-geometry-with-csg-js/) is another short tutorial on the subject.

Comment: thanks, how can i set the position of a cube now?
cube.position.set(x,y,z,); doesn't work :/